# Error C2065: undeclared identifier, even when the function is declared

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to call a function `randomFunction()` in `myClass.cpp` but I am getting

```
error C2065: randomFunction: undeclared identifier
```

The  `randomFunction()` is declared in `anotherClass.h` and I have included  `#include "anotherClass.h"` in `myClass.h`but still getting this error.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: need the fill code to understand. you can go through this for common causes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002.aspx

Comment: Could you provide a little more code? And a guess: did you include `myClass.h` in `myClass.cpp`? Most of the suggestions in these comments are given because we cannot see what your code looks like.

Comment: Also check if both classes are under differentt namespace

Comment: @Timo yes i have included the header file, i dont have the code in my hand right now, let me try regenerate it and post.

Comment: @Spanky i am little new to c++ and surely namespace declaration doesn't seem to be like it is in c# here. can you please tell where can i find the namespace declaration for a class? i have a feeling that they are different namespaces

Comment: namespace will be at the top of every file after the includes. The entire code (class, methods and variables) will be enclosed inside it . You can go through the http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/1-3a-a-first-look-at-cout-cin-endl-namespaces-and-using-statements/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm

Comment: Please post your two files, seeing the error reported, it must be very easy to figure out what's wrong for people familiar with C++...

Comment: @Spanky there is no code enclosed inside it but both header files says `using namespace StudentWork;` so i guess both are inside same namespace.

Comment: Is `randomFunction()` a global function declared in `anotherClass.h` or a member function of the class declared in `anotherClass.h`?

Comment: `randomFunction()` is a public member function of a class `CAnotherClass` defined inside `anotherClass.h`

Comment: And you are creating a `CAnotherClass` instance (example `CAnotherClass theInstance;`) and later you do `theInstance.randomFunction()`? If so, this should work....it's hard to help more without viewing the source code...

Comment: actually i can do that but for some reason i am avoiding, what i am trying to find is cant it access the function directly when it is even inside same namespace and definition has been included?

Comment: If it's a `static` member function of a class, you must call it with class name prefix (`CAnotherClass::randomFunction()`), if it's not `static`, you definitely need to have a instance of the class created to access the function.

Comment: Using namespace do not mean the classes are under that namespace. It just implies it is using something from that particular namespace. I don't think namespace is a problem then. Try out jpo38 solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `randomFunction()` **being** `static`:

```
class CAnotherClass
{
public:
    static void randomFunction();
};
```

Then, `randomFunction()` **can** be called without a `CAnotherClass` object being created, using this syntax:

```
CAnotherClass::randomFunction();
```

If you have `randomFunction()` **not being** `static`:

```
class CAnotherClass
{
public:
    void randomFunction();
};
```

Then, `randomFunction()` **cannot** be called without a `CAnotherClass` object being created, you then have to use this syntax:

```
CAnotherClass myInstance;
myInstance.randomFunction();
```

or:

```
CAnotherClass().randomFunction(); // temporary object creation
```

Note that, if `randomFunction()` is `static`, the two syntaxes above will also work.

PS: I tried to guess what the problem was without the source code....hope this will help!